# Setting up a Regex Pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am having some difficulty trying to create a working regex pattern for recognizing a string of file names.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\.)(t)(x)(t)(\\s$|\\,)");
```

When using a .find() from a matcher class on my sample input, say

```
"file1.txt,file2.txt "
```

I am returned true, which is fine, however other erroneous input also returns true.

This erroneous input includes strings such as:

```
"file1.txt,,file2.txt "

"file%.text "
```

I have been consulting this website as I have been trying to construct them, I'm pretty sure I am missing something rather obvious though. [Link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: Please post your sample input and expected output.

Comment: *"I'm not quite getting the results I would like."* which are...?

Comment: @user1803551, I should have explained myself a bit more for the first input listed, I would like it to return true, for the two secondary examples, those should return false.

Comment: I guess you are trying to get .txt extensions, one at least, and the others separated by commas. Try this ([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt)+(,[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt)*

Comment: Try an online regex checker... to learn how to get it right...

Answer (score 2):

May this help you:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\.\\w+)(?:,|$)");
String files = "file1.txt,file2.txt";
Matcher mFile = pattern.matcher(files);
while (mFile.find()) {
    System.out.println("file: " + mFile.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
file: file1.txt
file: file2.txt
```

With only `.txt` files: `(.*?\\.txt)(?:,|$)`

Comment: This expression gave me the results I was looking for, thank you very much @Nicolas.

Answer (score 2):

To validate your file name list, you can use the following solution:

```
//                                  | preceded by start of input, or
//                                  |    | comma, preceded itself by either word or space
//                                  |    |              | file name
//                                  |    |              |     | dot
//                                  |    |              |     |    | extension
//                                  |    |              |     |    |  | optional 1 space
//                                  |    |              |     |    |  |   | followed by end of input
//                                  |    |              |     |    |  |   |     | or comma, 
//                                  |    |              |     |    |  |   |     | followed itself by word character
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|(?<=[\\w\\s]),)(\\w+)(\\.)txt\\s?(?=$|,(?=\\w))");
String input = "file1.txt,file2.txt";
String badInput = "file3.txt,,file4.txt";
String otherBadInput = "file%.txt, file!.txt";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    // printing group 1: file name
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
m = pattern.matcher(badInput);
// won't find anything
while (m.find()) {
    // printing group 1: file name
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
m = pattern.matcher(otherBadInput);
// won't find anything
while (m.find()) {
    // printing group 1: file name
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
file1
file2
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Naive way :

```
    public boolean validateFileName(String string){
      String[] fileNames= string.split(",");
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\b[\w]*[.](txt)\b"); /*match complete name, not just pattern*/
      for(int i=0;i<fileNames.length;i++){
          Matcher m = p.matcher(fileNames[i]);
          if (!m.matches())
              return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\w+\\.txt)(,??|$))+");
```

The above Pattern lets "file1.txt,,file2.txt" pass, but does not get an empty file for the two commas.
The other Strings "file1.txt,file2.txt" and "file%txt" are processed correctly.